# Problem extracting words from dataframe

Tags: machine-learning, pandas, feature-extraction

I have the following dataset which is a **.json** file:

[image]

and I would like to get the first word for every string inside `lista_asm`, so I would like to get: jmp,push,uncomisd,...etc

what I am doing to do this is the following:

```
dataFrame['opcodes'] = dataFrame['lista_asm'].apply(lambda x:[i.split()[0] for i in x])
```

but it gives me back the following error message:

```
   3589             else:
   3590                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3591                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3592 
   3593         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-18-5506b5721bf1> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 dataFrame['opcodes'] = dataFrame['lista_asm'].apply(lambda x:[i.split()[0].strip() for i in x])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't understand what is wrong. Can somebody please help me?

[EDIT]Trying the code:

```
dataFrame['opcodes'] = dataFrame['lista_asm'].apply(lambda x:x[0].split(" ",2)[0])
```

and adding :

```
df = dataFrame[["opcodes", "semantic"]].copy()
df
```

I get:

[image]

what I would like to get is a list of the type **[push,mov,..]** and this for every row.

It seems like when I do `x[0]` it does not return the first element of the list, but returns the pharentesis, which is weird. Am I doing something wrong which I don't see?

My objective is to pre-process this dataset in order to feed features to my model, but I haveing hard times in doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing. So, as much as I understood from your examples, for each sample of *list_asm*, you want to extract the very first word from the string.

The thing you are doing wrong is treating the string as a list. That is, `['uncomisd xmm2, xmm2', 'jp 0x40', ...]` is considered as a string by python, not a list.

Thus, you need to extract the strings from your list first, then you can't take the first words from all these strings.

To achieve that, you can use a regular expression to find all the strings that are inside of quotes `'...'`.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

# Read the file into dataframe
dataFrame = pd.read_json("dataset.json", lines=True)


# First extract the strings the take the first word of each string  
dataFrame['opcodes'] = dataFrame['lista_asm'].apply(lambda x: [i.split()[0] for i in re.findall("'([^']*)'", x)])
print(dataFrame)
```

or modular form of the code would be:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

# Function to extract the first words from each string
def extractFirstWord(str):
    listOfWords = re.findall("'([^']*)'", str)
    return [i.split()[0] for i in listOfWords]

# Read the file into dataframe
dataFrame = pd.read_json("dataset.json", lines=True)


dataFrame['opcodes'] = dataFrame['lista_asm'].apply(lambda x: extractFirstWord(x))
print(dataFrame)
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried your suggestion, but I still get only the pharentesis.

Comment: Can you please provide the data by uploading it somewhere? at least some samples.

Comment: I have uploded it here: https://github.com/JHDOR/try

Comment: Are you sure, you are checking th right thing? Couse it works in my machine. Check the output and use the exact code I provided.

Comment: you are right. I have tried to rewrite the code from the biginning, and your code works. I don't know why this code is giving me a lot of problems, probably I have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you say "apply(lambda x:[i.split()[0] **for i in x**])"

As soon as you say apply, x is your list. So you can say following
"**apply(lambda x:x[0].split(" ", 2)[0])**"

Meaning you say take first element in the list, than split on " " and in two parts. And than take the first word (part) with the last [0]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But this returns just the first word for the first string of the list. I would like to get the first word for each string of the list for each row of the dataframe. (Sorry, I have posed the question not specifying really well this fact)

Comment: I see. Can you jsut add list comprehension my code and that should be it?

Comment: Sorry, my bad I misreaded the dataframe before. With your code, it returns only the pharentesis from the list, so '[', sorry I put ampther conlum close to that and misreaded.

Comment: I will edit the question, so it is clearer.